# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: poll_position

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-migrations

Here It is showing an error while mapping the position table with the candidate if I use ForeignKey relationship then it is also showing an error can anybody tell what is the problem.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Position(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class candidate(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.full_name, self.position.title)

class Registration(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dob=models.DateField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fname
```

error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/poll/candidate/
no such table: poll_position
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/poll/candidate/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: poll_position
Exception Location: C:\Users\Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 423, in execute
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Anil\\PycharmProjects\\E_Vote\\ovs',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\Anil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 01 Jun 2021 07:10:50 +0000
```

Comment: Seems, you haven't migrated it properly, try to del the previous migrations and then migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the migrations folder from your app and `db.sqilte3` file and then retry -:

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate

python manage.py createsuperuser
```

and then retry your error must be solved

Comment: I did it and it did not work showing this same errror